Proving the Fundamental group of the Klein Bottle
I'm trying to prove that the fundamental group of the Klein Bottle is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Z}\ast \mathrm{Z}_{2}$.
I have considered the square surface, with one pair of opposite sides with the same orientation, and the other with the opposite orientation. Then from this surface I removed a circular surface in the middle, forming two spaces connected by road, $A_{1}$ and $A_2$.
Then using the theorem of Seifert -Van Kampen we find that
$\pi_{1}(K)=\pi_{1}(A_{1})\ast \pi_{1}(A_{2})/N=\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}/N$ where
$N=\left\langle i_{1_{\ast }}(g)i_{2_{\ast }}^{-1}(g)|g\in \pi_{1}\left(A_{1}\cap A_{2}  \right) \right\rangle=\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathrm{\mathbb{Z}}/\left\langle  a,b|abab^{-1}=e\right\rangle$  , $\pi_{1}(A_{1})=\left\{ e \right\} $ , $\pi_{1}(A_{2})=\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}$ ,
And
$i_{1_{\ast }}:\pi_{1}\left( A_{1}\cap A_{2} \right)\longrightarrow \pi_{1}\left(A_{1}\right)$ ,
$i_{2_{\ast }}:\pi_{1}\left( A_{1}\cap A_{2} \right)\longrightarrow \pi_{1}\left(A_{2}\right)$
are the homomorphisms induced by the respective inclusions of $_1 , _2$ of the set $_1∩_2$ in $_1$ and $_2$ respectively.
My question is how to prove that $\pi_{1}(K)=\pi_{1}(A_{1})\ast \pi_{1}(A_{2})/N\cong\mathrm{Z}\ast \mathrm{Z}_{2}$ ?

You can't prove that, because it's wrong.

The correct answer is $\mathbb Z \star_{2\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z$ (properly understood).

As $abab^{-1}=e$ or $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$,$b^2ab^{-2}=a$, so $b^2$ commute with everything, and generated a central infinite cyclic group. The quotient of $K$ by $b^2=1$ or $b=b^{-1}$ is the group  generated by $a, b'$ with the unique relation $b'^2=1$, i.e. $Z*Z/2Z$, so $K$ is a central extension of your group.
